# Синтаксическая ошибка в sql запросе

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('{bel}', '{bel1}', '{alf}', '{alf1}', '{ncb}', '{ncb1}', '{time}')")
```

у меня вот такой запрос, все работает на linux но на винде ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Проверьте закрывающие скобки на предыдущих строках.

Comment: И кавычки. Кстати не используйте ф строки в sql - это не безопасно